# MS Access 2010 query pulls same records multiple times, sql challenge

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently working on a program that keeps track of my company's stock inventory, using ms Access 2010. I'm having a hard time getting the query, intended to show inventory, to display the information I want. The problem seems to be that the query pulls the same record multiple times, inflating the sums of reserved and sold product.

Background: 
My company stocks steel bars. We offer to cut the bars into pieces. From an inventory side, We want to track the length of each bar, from the moment it comes in to the warehouse, through it's time in the warehouse (where it might get cut into smaller pieces), until the entire bar is sold and gone.

Database:
The query giving problems, is consulting 3 tables;

- Barstock (with the following fields)

  - BatchNumber (all the bars recieved, beloning to the same production heat)
  - BarNo (the individual bar)
  - Orginial Length (the length of the bar when recieved at the stock

(BatchNumber and BarNo combined, is the primary key)

- Sales

  - ID (primary key)
  - BatchNumber
  - BarNo
  - Quantity Sold
- Reservation (a seller kan reserve some material, when a customer signals interest, but needs time to decide)

  - ID (Primary key)
  - BatchNumber
  - BarNo
  - Quantity reserved

I'd like to pull information from the three tables into one list, that displays:
-Barstock.orginial length As Received
- Sales.Quantity sold As Sold
- Recieved - Sold As On Stock
- reservation.Quantity Reserved As Reserved
- On Stock - Reserved As Available.

The problem is that I suck at sql. I've looked into union and inner join to the best of my ability, but my efforts have been in vain. I usually rely on the design view to produce the Sql statements I need. With design view, I've come up with the following Sql:

```
SELECT 
  BarStock.BatchNo
  , BarStock.BarNo
  , First(BarStock.OrgLength) AS Recieved
  , Sum(Sales.QtySold) AS SumAvQtySold
  , [Recieved]-[SumAvQtySold] AS [On Stock]
  , Sum(Reservation.QtyReserved) AS Reserved
  , ([On Stock]-[Reserved])*[Skjemaer]![Inventory]![unitvalg] AS Available
FROM 
  (BarStock 
    INNER JOIN Reservation ON (BarStock.BarNo = Reservation.BarNo) AND (BarStock.BatchNo = Reservation.BatchNo)
  ) 
    INNER JOIN Sales ON (BarStock.BarNo = Sales.BarNo) AND (BarStock.BatchNo = Sales.BatchNo)
GROUP BY 
  BarStock.BatchNo
  , BarStock.BarNo
```

I know that the query is pulling the same record multiple times because; 
- when I remove the GROUP BY term, I get several records that are exactley the same.
- There are however, only one instance of these records in the corresponding tables.

I hope I've been able to explain myself properly, please ask if I need to elaborate on anything.

Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem!

Comment: Create a query without the grouping based on the three tables, then remove a table and run the query. Repeat until you find the table that is causing the duplicates. Then either edit the query to avoid the duplicates or post sample data here for help.

Comment: BTW I imagine the problem is the Sales table.

Comment: Hi Remou, thank you for answering, and yes you are right - when I remove the sales table, the duplication of the reservation records ceases. Could you please give me a clue as to how you were able to give your prediction?

Comment: Barstock has a unique index on the join fields, so it is not that, Reservations does not, but it is unlikely to contain duplicates. Sales is the most likely.

Comment: @Remou, I'm sorry for being a complete idiot, but could you point me towards something to read up on - terms, sites, anything, because my first reaction to you last answer was; But the sales table doesn't contain any duplicates. So what duplication are we talking about. I don't have a clue.

Comment: Not all of this applies to Access, but it is a start: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html  It is always a good idea to read something like http://r937.com/relational.html

Comment: I started a very long answer, but something is striking me: how do you manage the length of the cut bars in `BarStock`? Also, `First()` is definitely not what you mean, the way you use it in your query could return absolutely anything.

Comment: @RenaudBompuis : Thank you for looking at my problem. THe length of the cut bars are managed as the difference between the original length when recieved, and the total amount of bar sold. I thought that this best complied with the normal form requirements, especially the one saying that information shouldn't be transitive. About first(): It finds the first original length of the record that has matching values in the batchNo and BarNo fields. These fields are the primary keys of the table, and so there can only be one record, and therefore only one first. Design view insisted on a value here.

Comment: @RenaudBompuis Hi Renaud, first off, thank you for that length answer below, I almost feel ashamed for having taken up that much of your time. Really appreciate it!!!!! Your rigth about First() - It doesn't do anything. But I made the SQL in design view, and design view required that I select a function for that parameter, I choose fist since it doesn't do anything. Should have explained it better in the previous post, but ran out of space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

!!! Checking some assumptions

From your database schema, it seems that:

- There *could* be multiple `Sales` records for a given `BatchNumber/BarNo` (for instance, I can imagine that multiple customers may have bought subsections of the same bar).
- There *could* be multiple `Reservation` records for a given `BatchNumber/BarNo` (for instance, multiple sections of the same bar could be 'reserved')

To check if you do indeed  have multiple records in those tables, try something like:

```
SELECT CountOfDuplicates
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfDuplicates
        FROM   Sales
        GROUP  BY BatchNumber & "," & BarNo)
WHERE  CountOfDuplicates > 1
```

If the query returns some records, then there are duplicates and it's probably why your query is returning incorrect values.

#### Starting from scratch

Now, the trick to your make your query work is to really think about what is the main data you want to show, and start from that:

- You basically want a list of all bars in the stock.
  Some of these bars may have been sold, or they may be reserved, but if they are not, you should show the Quantity available in Stock. Your current query would never show you that.
- For each bar in stock, you want to list the quantity sold and the quantity reserved, and combined them to find out the quantity remaining available.

So it's clear, your central data is the list of bars in stock.

Rather than try to pull everything into a single large query straight away, it's best to create simple queries for each of those goals and make sure we get the proper data in each case.

#### Just the Bars

From what you explain, each individual bar is recorded in the `BarStock` table.
As I said in my comment, from what I understand, all bars that are delivered have a single record in the `BarStock` table, without duplicates. So your main list against which your inventory should be measured is the `BarStock` table:

```
SELECT BatchNumber, 
       BarNo, 
       OrgLength
FROM   BarStock
```

#### Just the Sales

Again, this should be pretty straightforward: we just need to find out how much total length was sold for each `BatchNumber/BarNo` pair:

```
SELECT BatchNumber, 
       BarNo, 
       Sum(QtySold) AS SumAvQtySold
FROM   Sales
GROUP BY BatchNumber, BarNo
```

#### Just the Reservations

Same as for Sales:

```
SELECT BatchNumber,
       BarNo,
       SUM(QtyReserved) AS Reserved
FROM   Reservation
GROUP  BY BatchNumber, BarNo
```

#### Original Stock against Sales

Now, we should be able to combine the first 2 queries into one. I'm not trying to optimise, just to make the data work together:

```
SELECT BarStock.BatchNumber,
       BarStock.BarNo,
       BarStock.OrgLength,
       S.SumAvQtySold,
       (BarStock.OrgLength - Nz(S.SumAvQtySold)) AS OnStock
FROM   BarStock
LEFT JOIN (SELECT BatchNumber,
                  BarNo,
                  Sum(QtySold) AS SumAvQtySold
           FROM   Sales
           GROUP  BY BatchNumber, BarNo) AS S
  ON (BarStock.BatchNumber = S.BatchNumber) AND (BarStock.BarNo = S.BarNo)
```

We do a `LEFT JOIN` because there might be bars in stock that have not yet been sold.
If we did an `INNER JOIN`, we wold have missed these in the final report, leading us to believe that these bars were never there in the first place.

#### All together

We can now wrap the whole query in another `LEFT JOIN` against the reserved bars to get our final result:

```
SELECT BS.BatchNumber,
       BS.BarNo,
       BS.OrgLength,
       BS.SumAvQtySold,
       BS.OnStock,
       R.Reserved,
       (OnStock - Nz(Reserved)) AS Available
FROM   (SELECT BarStock.BatchNumber,
               BarStock.BarNo,
               BarStock.OrgLength,
               S.SumAvQtySold,
               (BarStock.OrgLength - Nz(S.SumAvQtySold)) AS OnStock
        FROM   BarStock
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT BatchNumber,
                          BarNo,
                          SUM(QtySold) AS SumAvQtySold
                   FROM   Sales
                   GROUP  BY BatchNumber,
                             BarNo) AS S
          ON (BarStock.BatchNumber = S.BatchNumber) AND (BarStock.BarNo = S.BarNo)) AS BS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT BatchNumber,
                  BarNo,
                  SUM(QtyReserved) AS Reserved
           FROM   Reservation
           GROUP  BY BatchNumber,
                     BarNo) AS R
  ON (BS.BatchNumber = R.BatchNumber) AND (BS.BarNo = R.BarNo)
```

Note the use of `Nz()` for items that are on the right side of the join: if there is no `Sales` or `Reservation` data for a given `BatchNumber/BarNo` pair, the values for `SumAvQtySold` and `Reserved` will be `Null` and will render `OnStock` and `Available` null as well, regardless of the actual quantity in stock, which would not be the result we expect.

Using the Query designer in Access, you would have had to create the 3 queries separately and then combine them.
Note though that the Query Designed isn't very good at dealing with multiple `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins, so I don't think you could have written the whole thing in one go.

#### Some comments

I believe you should read the information that @Remou gave you in his comments.
To me, there are some unfortunate design choices for this database: getting basic stock data should be as easy as s simple `SUM()` on the column that hold inventory records.

Usually, a simple way to track inventory is to keep track of each stock transaction:

- Incoming stock records have a + Quantity
- Outgoing stock records have a - Quantity
- The record should also keep track of the part/item/bar reference (or ID), the date and time of the transaction, and -if you want to manage multiple warehouses- which warehouse ID is involved.

So if you need to know the complete stock at hand for all items, all you need to do is something like:

```
SELECT BarID,
       Sum(Quantity)
FROM   StockTransaction
GROUP BY BarID
```

In your case, while `BatchNumber/BarNo` is your natural key, keeping them in a separate `Bar` table would have some advantages:

- You can use `Bar.ID` to get back the `Bar.BatchNumber` and `Bar.BarNo` anywhere you need it.
- You can use `BarID` as a foreign key in your `BarStock`, `Sales` and `Reservation` tables. It makes joins easier without having to mess with the complexities of compound keys.

There are things that Access allows that are not really good practice, such as spaces in table names and fields, which end up making things less readable (at least because you need to keep them between `[]`), less consistent with VBA variable names that represent these fields, and incompatible with other database that don't accept anything other than alphanumerical characters for table and field names (should you wish to up-size later or interface your database with other apps).

Also, help yourself by sticking to a single naming convention, and keep it consistent:

- Do not mix upper and lower case inconsistently: either use CamelCase, or lower case or UPPER case for everything, but always keep to that rule.
- Name tables in the singular -or the plural-, but stay consistent. I prefer to use the singular, like table `Part` instead of `Parts`, but it's just a convention (that has its own reasons).
- Spell correctly: it's `Received` not `Recieved`. That mistake alone may cost you when debugging why some query or VBA code doesn't work, just because someone made a typo.
- Each table should/must have an `ID` column. Usually, this will be an auto-increment that guarantees uniqueness of each record in the table. If you keep that convention, then foreign keys become easy to guess and to read and you never have to worry about some business requirement changing the fact that you could suddenly find yourself with 2 identical `BatchNumbers`, for some reason you can't fathom right now.

There are lots of debates about database design, but there are certain 'rules' that everyone agrees with, so my recommendation should be to strive for:

- Simplicity: make sure that each table records one kind of data, and does not contain redundant data from other tables (normalisation).
- Consistency: naming conventions are important. Whatever you choose, stick to it throughout your project.
- Clarity: make sure that you-in-3-years and other people can easily read the table names and fields and understand what they are without having to read a 300 page specification. It's not always possible to be that clear, but it's something to strive for.

Comment: Thank you again for your time and your answer. I appreciate your comments about the database design as well. I do not have much experience with relational db's so your input is welcome! Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: @Rookie you're welcome, I hope its was useful in helping you solve your issue.

Comment: Indeed it was. It is also valuable in terms of my sql education! Have an excellent day sir!